# Use a $variable inside a SQL string?

Tags: php, sql, variables

I would like to be able to select a category from a dropdown and depending on the category it will add it to whatever SQL table is it equal with.

```
<?php

$article = $_POST['article'];

$con = mysql_connect("******","******","*******");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("jstaltso_staltsoft", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO $article (headline, content)
VALUES ('$_POST[headline]', '$_POST[content]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "Content Added!";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<a href='articles.php'><- Back</a>";

mysql_close($con)

?>
```

I want the variable $articles to be in the place of where you out the name of the table.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $article (headline, content)
VALUES ('$_POST[headline]', '$_POST[content]')";
```

So whatever I choose in the dropdown, it will put it at $articles.

Comment: Lovely SQL injection holes you've got there.

Comment: Yup, the variable sits in the query string just like $_POST['something'] (noted you forgot to use quotes or double quotes for the index of your POST array)... but, what's the question? Also, using $_POST that way is quite unsafe, you know.

Comment: And so where is your question?

Comment: @Alfabravo Thats not an error.It will work fine

Comment: Cool, where will this application run? This will be heaven von SQL injection attacks.

Serisously, read up on SQL injections.

Comment: no won't work. look at my answer

Comment: Doesn't this code work?as far as i can see there is no error with the $articles.recheck any other portions,or at least tell us your current output.

Comment: This isn't used for anything public, no need to comment on that.

Comment: People are commenting on it to help you write secure code - its for your benefit and understanding

Comment: Sure, but then I would have asked for help securing my code :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
"INSERT INTO `{$article}` ...."
```

Don't forget to sanitize your input! (mysql_real_escape_string, for starters)

Comment: If you are getting the error incorrect table name followed by '', it seems to me that the variable $article isn't being set to a value.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use that type of variables, change last code to
`$sql="INSERT INTO $article (headline, content)
VALUES ('" . $_POST['headline'] " . ', '" . $_POST['content'] . "')";`

Comment: Sure, you cannot access Array-Variables in that quotes.

Comment: This gives me a syntax error. The code works fine if I add the name of the table myself.

Comment: ah theres another error, sry ill change the code above.. (That headline and content has to be quoted.

Comment: It will....just try...I have an web app that has been running for some four months with queries embedded with arrays like $_SESSION,$_POST..note:I use PHP5

Comment: I still get a syntax error.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/jstaltso/public_html/admin/articles_INS.php on line 13

Comment: Maybe that's depending on Server settings, usually you would get error "unexpected T_VARIABLE in ...". That's why its maybe working at your server.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/jstaltso/public_html/admin/articles_INS.php on line 13

Comment: hm. And line 13 is that $sql = "" ?

Comment: And you have a `;` after every line? What does line 12 look like?

Comment: mysql_select_db("jstaltso_staltsoft", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO $article (headline, content) VALUES ('" . $_POST['headline'] " . ', '" . $_POST['content'] . "')";

Comment: Hmm. Weird, I don't know why this error is caused than.. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. I never had a problem with that line of code anyway.
My problem is with $article not functioning inside that line of code :/

Comment: Maybe you should use `$article = mysql_real_escape_string($article);` but I don't know whether that could solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer won't be too helpful for you right now, but sice there is just too much wrong with that code and that approach, here are a few tips:

- Use PDO instead of PHP's MySQL functions. It'll seem daunting at first, especially if you haven't got any experience with object-oriented programming, but it's definately worth the effort.
- **Sanitize that `$article` value!** `if($article == 'foo' || $article == 'bar') {...}`
- The best ways to use variables in strings are: `"This is a ".$adjective." string"` and `"This is a {$adjective} string"`

Comment: I'm far from remotely skilled with PHP and SQL and this is just supposed to me something simple that I experiment with form time to time.

But I'll try to look into PDO.