# Wordpress update query not working

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have an update query which is not working for me. I am able to make selects quite happily on the same page but I cannot get an update statement to work.
The table is not a part of wordpress so Im wondering if that could be it or if I have just got something wrong.

```
$query = "UPDATE   login_count SET `count` = '100' WHERE  `user_id` = $userID ";
$insrt = $wpdb->query($query);
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.
Sometime query is working and some time it does not.
I have tried to find the error using last_query, but it does not show any error.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
$insrt = $wpdb->update(
                'login_count',    //table_name
                array('count'=>'100'),//data
                array('user_id'=>$userID),//where
                array('%s'),//data format
                array('%s')
                    );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$insrt = $wpdb->update( 
'login_count', //table_name
array( 
    'count' => '100',   // string   
), 
array( 'user_id' => $user_id ),  //Where Condition
array( 
    '%d',   // value1
), 
array( '%d' ) 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `..user_id = {$userID} ";`

**Edit**

See: [Use a $variable inside a SQL string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759372/use-a-variable-inside-a-sql-string)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12789242)

Comment: I wasn't asking for clarification? I was suggesting a solution; i.e. that not using the braces around the variable within the query string was the cause of the problem?

Comment: Then you could edit your answer removing _"Try this"_ and explaining a little bit about your solution, just like you just did in this comment ;)

Comment: Apologies, I presumed simply stating the need to add the braces was sufficient enough in explaining this *may* be the cause