# if condition in where clause in MySQL+ PHP

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have a variable in PHP. I want to check my PHP variable in MySQL query and if it is not null use it in a where clause.

```
select * from T1
where post = "news" and  $city = cityname and $city is not null
```

`$city` is PHP variable.

I have a problem when `$city` is null, that should show all news posts but it returns nothing.

this is my table:
[image]

Comment: `$city` is a column name ?

Comment: You should not even need the `$city IS NOT NULL` check, AFAIK.  By the way, you should read about how to use prepared statements in PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a $variable inside a SQL string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759372/use-a-variable-inside-a-sql-string)

Comment: @executable no it's my variable in PHP.

Comment: Yes, but the `value` refer to a column name ?

Comment: You should post your PHP code here

Comment: @executable no i got a number by post method and i wanna use that in my where

Comment: @Smollet777 i have a problem when $city is null , I mean when $city = 7 . I don't have any problem but when it is null , that should show all of news

Comment: $_POST['city'];
$city= $_POST['city'];

Comment: So you have column with name "7" ?

Comment: I think you need to reverse like `cityname = $city`

Comment: @Eakethet no is a field in id column and I wanna get other fields of that row.

Comment: Can you show the table `T1` ?

Comment: you can't use IS NOT NULL in _SQL_ to check the status of a _PHP_ variable. It can only be used to check the value in your column. Instead in PHP you should check this value before deciding whether to add the condition to the WHERE clause of your query or not. Currently if $city is null then your query will end up like `select * from T1
where post = "news" and  NULL = cityname and NULL is not null` which just makes no sense at all.

Comment: Equally if $city is populated, then it will be like `select * from T1
where post = "news" and  7 = cityname and 7 is not null`. Which will work but the last bit is totally redundant. You probably ought to make it into `cityname = $city` for readability as well, that's the conventional way to write it.

Comment: Basically you need some PHP which will check if $city is null or not, and then decide whether to add the `and cityname = $city` part to the SQL or not. And you should use parameterised queries as well, to save yourself from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: If you get this value from a form (`$_POST['city']`), then most likely it is never NULL to begin with, but rather an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `$city` is a PHP variable, if it is `NULL` then when you echo it in your query you will simply get nothing. That will make an invalid query; it will look like this:

```
select * from T1
where post = "news" and   = cityname and  is not null
```

To make this work, you need to enclose `$city` in your query in quotes, and then rather than comparing it to `NULL`, compare it to the empty string i.e.

```
select * from T1
where post = "news" and  ('$city' = cityname or '$city' = '')
```

Note that the correct logical operator is `or` for this use case.

As was pointed out in the comments, you should look into prepared statements. This question has some really useful information: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select * from T1
where post = "news" and  ($city = cityname or $city is not null )
```

Comment: please mention description

Comment: Can you explain how that solves the problem? There is no colum named `$city`